# How would I prove the identity $(x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$, if a true identity at all?

Tags: solution-verification, physics

In going through old Monterey Physics Flash Games, I approached this current step in some derivation in connection to an elastic collision, where an identity was referenced.

[$(x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvbKI.jpg)

However, I have never even heard of this identity; I can not find it online, and in plugging in $x=3$ and $y=5$ (arbitrarily) results in different values. Is this even a real identity? Why is it used if it is not true? If there is some truth in it, how would I prove it? I am in general confused as to why this constitutes a logical step in derivation if it is not even true. (As another point of consideration, is this identity true only for certain values?)

Comment: The image says $x^2\color{red}{-}y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$

Comment: If you plugged in $x = 3$ and $y = 5$ and got different values then it's not an identity (unless you don't trust your ability to perform arithmetic reliably; in any case you can plug it into a calculator).

Comment: $(x-y)(x+y) = x^2-yx+xy-y^2 = x^2-y^2$ I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why u are asking something that is so famous in this world ??

Comment: That's called a difference of two squares. It is a very well-known identity. Can you redo you internet search now?

Comment: don't u think it is as easy as : 9-25=(-2)(8) ?? I don't knw what is  ur problem do u want some downvotes for it ??

Comment: "Identity" left me in an anchoring bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that for any numbers

$$a\times (b+c)=a\times b+a\times c$$

Let’s apply that with $a=x-y$ and $b=x$, $c=y$

We then have

$$(x-y)\times (x+y)=(x-y)\times x+(x-y)\times y$$

Doing the same with $(x-y)\times x=x^2-y\times x$ and $(x-y)\times y=x\times y-y^2$ and adding all that together we get

$$(x-y)\times (x+y)=x^2+x\times y-y\times x-y^2=x^2-y^2$$